# Add IDs when using json_normalize

Tags: python, json

I have the following dictionary. I want to flat the `answers` and keep the IDs in each line. I am using the `meta` argument from the `pd.json_normalize` function but it keeps me throwing an error

```
my_dict = {'id': ['123', '456', '789'],
          'answers': [
              {'answer_1': 0,
               'answer_2': 3342,
               'answer_3': '0'},
              {'answer_1': 4,
               'answer_2': 141,
               'answer_3': '4'},
              {'answer_1': 9,
               'answer_2': 345,
               'answer_3': '0'}, 
                ]
          }
```

My desired output is:

```
id    answer_1  answer_2    answer_3
123   0         3342        0
456   4         141         4
789   9         345         0
```

But when I call the function I have an error

```
pd.json_normalize(my_dict, record_path = 'answers', meta = 'id')
ValueError: Length of values (9) does not match length of index (3)
```

If I call `json_normalize` without `meta` argument it works fine, the only thing is that I do not get the IDs I need

```
pd.json_normalize(my_dict, record_path = 'answers')
answer_1    answer_2    answer_3
0           3342        0
4           141         4
9           345         0
```

I have already used `[]` and `[[]]` both in `record_path` and `meta` arguments but I cannot get my desired output. How can I flat the `answers` and still keep the IDs?